# Strata Sampling in R

Tags: r, sampling

Sorry but i am newbie on this program. I have some problem, as title mean, because R give me the following error not enough obervations in the stratum 5. I must do a strata sampling on five provinces of Campania (Italy), i have a data like that:

```
dati1$Rip <- matrix(dati1$A3.factor, nrow=N, ncol=1)
dati1$A3.factor <- factor(dati1$A3, labels=c("Av","Bn","Ce","Na","Sa"))
dati1$A3.factor
[1] Sa Bn Sa Sa Sa Sa Sa Sa Sa Sa Sa Sa Av Sa Sa Bn Bn Bn Sa Bn Bn Bn Bn Bn Bn
[26] Bn Sa Bn Sa Bn Sa Bn Bn Na Av Bn Bn Av Sa Bn Bn Bn Sa Bn Bn Sa Sa Bn Bn Bn
[51] Av Bn Bn Bn Bn Sa Bn Sa Bn Bn Bn Sa Sa Na Sa Av Sa Bn Bn Bn Sa Sa Bn Sa Sa
[76] Sa Sa Na Bn Bn Bn Av Av Bn Bn Bn Bn Bn Bn Bn Bn Na Bn Bn Sa Bn Ce Na Ce Sa
Levels: Av Bn Ce Na Sa
```

The problem is that when i do

```
    library(sampling)
    N <- dim(dati1)[1]
    N
    a <- 0.05
    z_a <- qnorm(1-a/2)  
    error <- 0.20
    Vo <- error^2/z_a^2
    Vo  
    n <- ((Vo/p*(1-p)) + (1/N))^(-1)
    n <- round(n)
    n
    ripartizione <- factor(dati1$A3, labels=c("Av","Bn","Ce","Na","Sa"))
    Nh <- table(ripartizione)
    Nh
    f <- (n/N)*Nh 
    f
    nh <-round(f)
    nh
```

So nh is

```
    Av Bn Ce Na Sa 
    3 25  1  2 17
```

From an N of:

```
    Av Bn Ce Na Sa 
    7 51  2  5 35
```

Why when i give the command :

```
        sample.strata <- strata(dati1,c("Rip"), size=c(3,25,1,2,17), "srswor", TRUE)
        sample.strata
```

R says

```
        error in strata(dati1, c("Rip"), size = c(3, 25, 1, 2, 17), "srswor",  : 
          not enough obervations in the stratum 5
```

What must i do?

Answer (score 4):

The `help(strata)` page tells you to sort the data.frame. So this succeeds:

```
sample.strata <- strata(dati1[order(dati1$Rip),],c("Rip"), 
                               size=c(3,25,1,2,17), "srswor", TRUE)
```

Making it a matrix will of course turn a factor into its numeric underpinnings, so if you were hoping to have meaningful labels, you have 'shot yourself in the foot' by using matrix format.

```
> table(sample.strata$Stratum)

 1  2  3  4  5 
 3 25  1  2 17
```